# php numeric array

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner and I want to do the following:

I want to compare an array of numbers to an itemid.  Currently, my code only works if I state which position of the array to check (productId). How can I check productId to test the whole contents of the array?

```
$productId = array(146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,158,159,160,161,162,
                   163,113,116,117,118,114,119,120,121,115,121,122,123,124);

if(($_REQUEST['view'] == 'article') && ( $_REQUEST['Itemid'] == $productId[0])) {
    $setCol = 1;
    $setId = "main-noleft"; 
} else {
    $setCol = null;
    $setId = "main";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
in_array($_REQUEST['Itemid'], $productId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in_array` function: http://php.net/in_array

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also use this
array_search( $_REQUEST['Itemid'], $productId )
```

array_search
Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful 
[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)